# Unable to send a message from a child process back to the parent process

Tags: c, pipe, fork

I am trying to understand how pipes and forking work. So I wrote a simple program where a parent process sends a message to the child process (which works fine). But if I try to send a message back from the child process by adding the commented code, it stops working. And the execution of the program stops after outputting "Parent sent: hello".

```
int main() {
    int child_to_parent[2];
    int parent_to_child[2];
    pipe(child_to_parent);
    pipe(parent_to_child);

    pid_t id = fork();

    if (id == 0) {
        close(parent_to_child[1]);
        close(child_to_parent[0]);
        FILE* out = fdopen(child_to_parent[1], "w");
        FILE* in = fdopen(parent_to_child[0], "r");

        char msg[6];
        fscanf(in ,"%s", msg);
        printf("Child got: %s\n", msg);
        /*
        fprintf(out, "hi ");
        printf("Child sent: hi\n"); 
        */
    } else {
        close(parent_to_child[0]);
        close(child_to_parent[1]);
        FILE* in = fdopen(child_to_parent[0], "r");
        FILE* out = fdopen(parent_to_child[1], "w");

        fprintf(out, "hello");
        printf("Parent sent: hello\n");
        /*
        char msg[3];
        fscanf(in, "%s", msg);
        printf("Parent got: %s\n", msg);
        */
    }
}
```

And I can't figure out why. What confuses me the most is why the child process can't even receive the message after I modified the code. Could anyone please tell me what's wrong, or direct me in the right direction?

Comment: Probably because of buffering. I recommend not mixing stdio / `FILE` with file descriptors / pipes.

Comment: You need to flush the output from the parent, or close the stream from parent to child.  The output will be fully buffered, and you don’t write a buffer full.

Comment: Yes - try putting `fflush(0);` after the parent's write, but before it's read.

Comment: if you want to use `fscanf("%s", ...)` you need to sent a separator (a space or \n for instance) after the word to not block _fscanf_ and of course to read the separator character after, the _fflush_ is necessary after the _fwrite_. I put 3 ways in my answer read/write then fread/fwrite(&fflush) then finally a little change from your code with the additional separator (&fflush)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First solution using read/write to exchange any number of messages

Here I indicate the end of each buffer to read by a \n :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

void rd(int fd, int child)
{
  char c;
  int first = 1;

  do {
    if (!read(fd, &c, 1))
      break;
    if (first) {
      printf("%s got:", (child) ? "Child" : "Parent");
      first = 0;
    }
    putchar(c);
  } while (c != '\n');
}

void wr(int fd, const char * msg, int child)
{
  write(fd, msg, strlen(msg));
  printf("%s sent:%s", (child) ? "Child" : "Parent", msg);
}

int main() {
    int child_to_parent[2];
    int parent_to_child[2];

    pipe(child_to_parent);
    pipe(parent_to_child);

    pid_t id = fork();

    if (id == 0) {
      close(parent_to_child[1]);
      close(child_to_parent[0]);

      rd(parent_to_child[0], 1);
      wr(child_to_parent[1], "hi\n", 1);

      rd(parent_to_child[0], 1);
      wr(child_to_parent[1], "fine, and you ?\n", 1);

      rd(parent_to_child[0], 1);
    } else {
      close(parent_to_child[0]);
      close(child_to_parent[1]);

      wr(parent_to_child[1], "hello\n", 0);
      rd(child_to_parent[0], 0);

      wr(parent_to_child[1], "how are you ?\n", 0);
      rd(child_to_parent[0], 0);

      wr(parent_to_child[1], "fine too\n", 0);
    }
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wextra p.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out 
Parent sent:hello
Child got:hello
Child sent:hi
Parent got:hi
Parent sent:how are you ?
Child got:how are you ?
Child sent:fine, and you ?
Parent got:fine, and you ?
Parent sent:fine too
Child got:fine too
```

---

It is also possible to use *fread/fwrite*, *fflush* is necessary after *fwrite* to not be blocked. It is fortunately not necessary to close the pipe after sending  to be able to read and answer, else only one message can be exchanged. I still use \n to indicate the end of the buffer sent :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

void rd(FILE * fd, int child)
{
  char c;
  int first = 1;

  do {
    if (!fread(&c, 1, 1, fd))
      break;
    if (first) {
      printf("%s got:", (child) ? "Child" : "Parent");
      first = 0;
    }
    putchar(c);
  } while (c != '\n');
}

void wr(FILE *  fd, const char * msg, int child)
{
  fwrite(msg, strlen(msg), 1, fd);
  fflush(fd);
  printf("%s sent:%s", (child) ? "Child" : "Parent", msg);
}

int main() {
    int child_to_parent[2];
    int parent_to_child[2];
    pipe(child_to_parent);
    pipe(parent_to_child);

    pid_t id = fork();

    if (id == 0) {
        close(parent_to_child[1]);
        close(child_to_parent[0]);
        FILE* out = fdopen(child_to_parent[1], "w");
        FILE* in = fdopen(parent_to_child[0], "r");

    rd(in, 1);
    wr(out, "hi\n", 1);

    rd(in, 1);
    wr(out, "fine, and you ?\n", 1);

    rd(in, 1);
    } else {
        close(parent_to_child[0]);
        close(child_to_parent[1]);
        FILE* in = fdopen(child_to_parent[0], "r");
        FILE* out = fdopen(parent_to_child[1], "w");

    wr(out, "hello\n", 0);
    rd(in, 0);

    wr(out, "how are you ?\n", 0);
    rd(in, 0);

    wr(out, "fine too\n", 0);
    }
}
```

Compilation and execution:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wextra pp.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Parent sent:hello
Child got:hello
Child sent:hi
Parent got:hi
Parent sent:how are you ?
Child got:how are you ?
Child sent:fine, and you ?
Parent got:fine, and you ?
Parent sent:fine too
Child got:fine too
```

---

And finally if you want to use `fscanf("%s", ...)` **you need to sent a separator (a space or \n for instance) after the word to not block *fscanf* and of course to also read the separator character**, the *fflush* is necessary after the *fwrite*.

If I change a little you program :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    int child_to_parent[2];
    int parent_to_child[2];
    pipe(child_to_parent);
    pipe(parent_to_child);

    pid_t id = fork();

    if (id == 0) {
      close(parent_to_child[1]);
      close(child_to_parent[0]);
      FILE* out = fdopen(child_to_parent[1], "w");
      FILE* in = fdopen(parent_to_child[0], "r");
      char msg[16], c;

      fscanf(in ,"%s%c", msg, &c);
      printf("Child got: %s\n", msg);

      fprintf(out, "hi ");
      fflush(out);
      printf("Child sent: hi\n"); 

      fscanf(in ,"%s%c", msg, &c);
      printf("Child got: %s\n", msg);

      fprintf(out, "fine,you? ");
      fflush(out);
      printf("Child sent: fine,you?\n"); 

      fscanf(in ,"%s%c", msg, &c);
      printf("Child got: %s\n", msg);
    } else {
      close(parent_to_child[0]);
      close(child_to_parent[1]);
      FILE* in = fdopen(child_to_parent[0], "r");
      FILE* out = fdopen(parent_to_child[1], "w");

      fprintf(out, "hello\n");
      fflush(out);
      printf("Parent sent: hello\n");

      char msg[16], c;

      fscanf(in, "%s%c", msg, &c);
      printf("Parent got: %s\n", msg);

      fprintf(out, "how-are-you? ");
      fflush(out);
      printf("Parent sent: how-are-you?\n");

      fscanf(in, "%s%c", msg, &c);
      printf("Parent got: %s\n", msg);

      fprintf(out, "fine-too ");
      fflush(out);
      printf("Parent sent: fine-too\n");
    }
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wextra ppp.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Parent sent: hello
Child got: hello
Child sent: hi
Parent got: hi
Parent sent: how-are-you?
Child got: how-are-you?
Child sent: fine,you?
Parent got: fine,you?
Parent sent: fine-too
Child got: fine-too
```

Answer (score 0):

`fscanf` reads until some whitespace character (as given by `isspace`) is found when you use `%s`, yet you're not sending one. So `fscanf` never returns, because it's waiting for the whitespace.

Use `fread` and `fwrite` instead of `fscanf` and `fprintf` and your pipes will work.

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy Which it isn't if the commented-out code is added back in. Right now, the process exits, closing the stream; if the commented-out code is uncommented, both processes go into `fscanf` and become deadlocked, waiting for one another to send a whitespace character.

Answer (score 0):

In both the parent and the child, when you have finished writing to the pipe, flush the buffers with `fflush` and close the pipe write ends with `close`.

Here is a slightly modified program:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

FILE *fdopen(int fd, const char *mode);

int main() {
    int child_to_parent[2];
    int parent_to_child[2];
    pipe(child_to_parent);
    pipe(parent_to_child);

    pid_t id = fork();

    if (id == 0) {
        close(parent_to_child[1]);
        close(child_to_parent[0]);
        FILE* out = fdopen(child_to_parent[1], "w");
        FILE* in = fdopen(parent_to_child[0], "r");

        char msg[6];
        printf("Child gonna read...\n");
        fscanf(in ,"%s", msg);
        printf("Child got: %s\n", msg);

        fprintf(out, "hi");
        fflush(out);
        printf("Child sent: hi\n");
        close(child_to_parent[1]);
    } else {
        close(parent_to_child[0]);
        close(child_to_parent[1]);
        FILE* in = fdopen(child_to_parent[0], "r");
        FILE* out = fdopen(parent_to_child[1], "w");

        fprintf(out, "hello");
        printf("Parent sent: hello\n");
        fflush(out);
        close(parent_to_child[1]);

        char msg[3];
        printf("Parent gonna read...\n");
        fscanf(in, "%s", msg);
        printf("Parent got: %s\n", msg);
    }
}
```

Output when I run it:

```
Parent sent: hello
Parent gonna read...
Child gonna read...
Child got: hello
Child sent: hi
Parent got: hi
```